# In TypeORM, how do I query a property of a property in my where clause?

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm, relation

I'm using NestJS 10 and TypeORM 0.3.17.  I have created this zip code entity,

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  JoinColumn,
  Column,
  Unique,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Country } from './country.entity';
import { Region } from './region.entity';

@Entity()
@Unique(['zipCode', 'region'])
export class ZipCode {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  zipCode: string;

  @Column()
  city: string;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Region, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'region_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  region: Region;
}
```

with this associated region entity

```
@Entity()
@Unique(['name', 'country'])
export class Region {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  abbrev: string;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Country)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'country_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  country: Country;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write a TypeORM query such that I can search for a zip code based on the zip code and the region's associated country code.  I Have tried this

```
export class ZipCodeRepository extends Repository<ZipCode> {
    ...
  async findByZipCode(zipCode: string, countryCode: string): Promise<ZipCode> {
    return this.zipCodeRepository.findOne({
      select: ['zipCode', 'city'],
      relations: ['region'],
      where: { region: { country: {countryCode: countryCode} } },
    });
```

but this fails with the compilaton error,

```
Type '{ country: { countryCode: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FindOperator<any> | FindOptionsWhere<Region> | FindOptionsWhere<Region>[] | EqualOperator<Region>'.
  Types of property 'country' are incompatible.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'countryCode' does not exist in type 'FindOperator<any> | FindOptionsWhere<Country> | FindOptionsWhere<Country>[] | EqualOperator<Country>'.
```

What is the proper way to construct the associated query?

Answer (score 0):

you should add country relation in the region like this:

```js
async findByZipCode(zipCode: string, countryCode: string): Promise<ZipCode> {
    return this.zipCodeRepository.findOne({
      select: ['zipCode', 'city'],
      relations: ['region','region.country'],
      where: { region: { country: {countryCode: countryCode} } },// ensure countryCode field must have inside country
    });
```

Comment: please give me a bounty if my answer is helpful :D

Comment: I did not read my own error message clearly -- "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'countryCode' does not exist in type" means I was trying to use an attribute "countryCode" that didn't exist in my "country" object.  In my case, I had defined the attribute "code" instead of "countryCode" and using that fixed the error.